# Installing and using Sweet Modal Vue npm package in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, npm, vue.js, homestead

So I have been searching through Stack Overflow and reading to the responses to similar questions as this but they have not helped me at all in better understanding this:

I wanted to use this Sweet Modal Vue package ( https://sweet-modal-vue.adepto.as/ ) for my Laravel 5.6 project (I am using the Laravel Homestead setup btw). Installed it via npm and it is contained within my node_modules folder.

Now I am trying to use it within my project. I have tried following the instructions on the documentation to no avail, after which I tried using

```
window.SweetModalVue = require('sweet-modal-vue');
```

in the app.js file first and then tried I tried using it in the bootstrap.js file. And after I compile and try inserting

```
<sweet-modal>Well Hello There</sweet-modal>
```

in my blade template code, I keep getting an error message of

> ReferenceError: SweetModal is not defined

I don't see any tutorials at all (articles or video tutorials) on how this process works on Laravel 5.6. Could anyone let me know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can install component globally

```
const SweetModal = require('sweet-modal-vue/plugin.js').default
Vue.use(SweetModal)
```

then in your code

```
<sweet-modal>Well Hello There</sweet-modal>
```